# build/core/droiddoc.mk:158 Too many words (5411). Stop

Tags: android, android-sdk-manager

I try to run 
make update-api

but i git this error

> target Static Jar: android-support-v7-mediarouter-jellybean-mr1
>   (out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v7-mediarouter-jellybean-mr1_intermediates/javalib.jar)
>   target Java: android-support-v7-mediarouter-jellybean-mr2
>   (out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v7-mediarouter-jellybean-mr2_intermediates/classes)
>   Copying:
>   out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v7-mediarouter-jellybean-mr2_intermediates/classes-jarjar.jar Copying:
>   out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v7-mediarouter-jellybean-mr2_intermediates/emma_out/lib/classes-jarjar.jar
>   Copying:
>   out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v7-mediarouter-jellybean-mr2_intermediates/classes.jar
>   target Static Jar: android-support-v7-mediarouter-jellybean-mr2
>   (out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v7-mediarouter-jellybean-mr2_intermediates/javalib.jar)
>   target Java: android-support-v7-mediarouter
>   (out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v7-mediarouter_intermediates/classes)
>   Copying:
>   out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v7-mediarouter_intermediates/classes-jarjar.jar
>   Copying:
>   out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v7-mediarouter_intermediates/emma_out/lib/classes-jarjar.jar
>   Copying:
>   out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v7-mediarouter_intermediates/classes.jar
>   target Java: android-support-v7-palette
>   (out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v7-palette_intermediates/classes)
>   Copying:
>   out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v7-palette_intermediates/classes-jarjar.jar Copying:
>   out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v7-palette_intermediates/emma_out/lib/classes-jarjar.jar
>   Copying:
>   out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v7-palette_intermediates/classes.jar
>   target Java: android-support-v8-renderscript
>   (out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v8-renderscript_intermediates/classes)
>   Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations. Note:
>   Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details. Copying:
>   out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v8-renderscript_intermediates/classes-jarjar.jar
>   Copying:
>   out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v8-renderscript_intermediates/emma_out/lib/classes-jarjar.jar Copying:
>   out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v8-renderscript_intermediates/classes.jar
>   build/core/droiddoc.mk:158: *** Too many words (5411). Stop.
>
> make failed to build some targets (06:10 (mm:ss))

Please help me..Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please include more information about your environment (IDE you are using, project settings, build configuration, etc.)

Comment: I just added the new lib in /framworks/base/core/java/android , compilation is good but i dont know why i got this error , i use ubuntu 14.04 openjdk1.7 , gcc 4.8.4 , android 5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after wasting a day, this is the answer,
so, the number of words in droiddoc is limited to 5000 see 
@build/core/definitions.mk,

for me i had more than 5000, so the error "TO many words"

so the solution is to modified the var dump-words-to-file

before modif

```
# dump-words-to-file, <word list>, <output file>
```

define dump-words-to-file
        @rm -f $(2)
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 1,200,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 201,400,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 401,600,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 601,800,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 801,1000,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 1001,1200,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 1201,1400,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 1401,1600,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 1601,1800,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 1801,2000,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 2001,2200,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 2201,2400,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 2401,2600,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 2601,2800,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 2801,3000,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 3001,3200,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 3201,3400,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 3401,3600,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 3601,3800,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 3801,4000,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 4001,4200,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 4201,4400,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 4401,4600,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 4601,4800,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 4801,5000,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(if $(wordlist 5001,5002,$(1)),$(error Too many words ($(words $(1)))))
endef

after modif is :

```
# dump-words-to-file, <word list>, <output file>
```

define dump-words-to-file
        @rm -f $(2)
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 1,200,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 201,400,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 401,600,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 601,800,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 801,1000,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 1001,1200,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 1201,1400,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 1401,1600,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 1601,1800,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 1801,2000,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 2001,2200,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 2201,2400,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 2401,2600,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 2601,2800,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 2801,3000,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 3001,3200,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 3201,3400,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 3401,3600,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 3601,3800,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 3801,4000,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 4001,4200,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 4201,4400,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 4401,4600,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 4601,4800,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(call emit-line,$(wordlist 4801,5400,$(1)),$(2))
        @$(if $(wordlist 5401,5402,$(1)),$(error Too many words ($(words $(1)))))
endef

and the error is gone. :)